# Unable to retrieve value from settings file inside custom module

Tags: 8

I have some specific values that will never change. I could use `define` and set them as constants but having a `module_name.settings.yml` file seems more appropriate.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the values from that file. It always ends up in `null`.

I have a module `my_module` in `docroot/modules/custom', it's installed. Inside the root of the module I've created a`my_module.settings.yml`file with a single entry of`hello: 'world'`.

I've tried retrieving it using:

```
(\Drupal::config('my_module.settings'))->get('hello')
```

But the returned value is `null`. According to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8) it should be working fine.

I'm using Drupal 8.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this file into

> myModule/config/install/my_module.settings.yml

Then uninstall and reinstall.

You ll get your value.